# Sum qty with jquery calculation plugins

Tags: jquery

how possibily to know sum of the total qty from the whole product in the table, also, how to automatically give it number like 1, 2, 3 before the item qty

any advice will be appreciated

Fiddle Here [>>](http://jsfiddle.net/0e87jvor/1/)

```
<table width="500">
                <col style="width: 50px;" />
                <col />
                <col style="width: 60px;" />
                <col style="width: 110px;" />
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        No #
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Qty
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        Product
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="qty_item_1" id="qty_item_1" value="1" size="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.packtpub.com/jQuery/book">Learning jQuery</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="price_item_1">
                        $39.99
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="total_item_1">
                        $39.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="qty_item_2" id="qty_item_2" value="1" size="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery Donation</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="price_item_2">
                        $14.99
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="total_item_2">
                        $14.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total QTY</td>
                    <td>?</td>

                    <td colspan="3" align="right">
                        <strong>Grand Total:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="grandTotal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Thanks

Warmly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `recalc` function:

```
var qtyTotals = 0;
$("input[name^=qty_item_]").each(function () {
    qtyTotals += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
$("#qtyTotal").text(qtyTotals);
```

Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/0e87jvor/2/